# Переход по кнопке ОК

Tags: javascript, html

Только при нажатии кнопки Ответить должно переходить на страницу [example.com](http://example.com)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function F1() {
            if (document.getElementById("text").value == '4') alert('Молодец!');
            else alert('Подумай еще!');
        }
    </script>
    <b>2+2=</b>
    <input id="text" name="text" type="text" value="">
    <input OnClick="F1();" name="button" type="button" value="Ответить">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажимай + если помогло

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="JavaScript"><!--
        function F1() {
            if (document.getElementById("text").value == '4') {
                alert('Молодець!');
                window.location.href = "http://www.154.org.ua/7-b";
            } else {
                alert('Подумай ще!');
            }
        }
    // --></script>
    <b>2+2=</b>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Ответить" OnClick="F1();">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Да блин одно и тоже, только вообще полностью готовый код, может вы свяжетесь с ТСом и напишите все за него?:)

Comment: Вы не подскажете, чем отличается знак \/ от этого \\?

Comment: смотря в чем код!
если // то это коментарий
если в этом случае он маскирует ковычку " \" "
ну может еще так var a = /[0-9][A-Z]ig/ тогда это регулярное выражение

Comment: Смотрите я делаю сайт и у меня страница в папке математика, а фотографии в папке pages and images какой html код надо поставить? Когда страница в папке pages and images то фотки видно, а когда в папке Математика то просто маленький квадратик с розорваним листочком(что ссылка есть, а файл в другой папке) пресунуть фотку в папку математика я не могу. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если мы хотим вывести фото с папки "pages and images" находясь в папке "математика" и эти папки на одном уровне тогда

в данном случае // обозначает переход на главный под католог

<img href="/pages and images/1.jpg">
или так 
<img href="../pages and images/1.jpg">

Comment: Если мы хотим вывести фото с папки "pages and images", находясь в папке "математика" и эти папки на одном уровне тогда в данном случае / обозначает переход на главный подкаталог

    img src="/pages and images/1.jpg"

или так 

    img src="../pages and images/1.jpg"
           
`<img src="http://content.foto.mail.ru/mail/jon-536/_myphoto/i-132.jpg" />`

Comment: Но папка математика находится в pages and images

Comment: ТС быть может вам стоит подучить матчасть? Хотя-бы html, я не говорю о  JavaScript...

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь свойством location:

```
function F1() {
    if (document.getElementById("text").value == '4') {
        alert('Молодець!');
        window.location.href = "http://www.154.org.ua/7-b";
    } else {
        alert('Подумай ще!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно полностью

Comment: Дык я посностью скопировал код вашей функции и добавил location по условию есть alert молодец) или что надо?)

Comment: Полностью начиная с <html> и заканчивая </html>

Comment: ппц..ты что не можешь сравнить 2 функции и найти что там всего одна строка добавилась???? Вместо этого какой то.. скопировал мой код и ты принял его ответ. Я в шоке

Comment: Он реально тупит =)

Comment: я тебе кнопочку нажал со с большим пальцем вверх =)

Comment: Без обид чувак.